# How to extend STDOUT and STDERR with environment context information in Linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, logging, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the situation where I need to add extra information to every output line from an execution is a Linux shell environment for which I can control the initialization, but I cannot (do not want to) control the execution of the scripts/commands in that context.

To better explain the problem, imagine that I have a Linux shell environment that is made available for executing steps (jobs) of a CI (continuous integration) pipeline.

The commands executed in the pipeline step are stored in different repositories managed by different people/teams and use the provided shell environment for execution, eg:

```sh
echo "command 1"
echo "command 2"
```

The output for the execution will look like:

```
command 1
command 2
```

The output for the commands above should have the pattern `<timestamp>:<project_id>:<pipeline_id>:<pipeline_step>:<message>` and look like:

```sh
143437560909100:9876:123456789:UnitTests:command 1
143437560909110:9876:123456789:UnitTests:command 2
```

The information in the pattern is available in the shell as:

- `<timestamp>`: simple `date +%H%M%S%N` shell execution
- `<project_id>`: available as environment variable `PROJECT_ID`
- `<pipeline_id>`: available as environment variable `PIPELINE_ID`
- `<pipeline_step>`: available as environment variable `PIPELINE_STEP`

The logs from a build/release execution are sent to a central logging service that allows me to correlate and analyze the behavior of the pipelines.

As I execute a lot of steps, some in parallel, from different pipelines (pipelines triggered by other pipelines) on different machines and sometimes even on different CI servers, I need to add to every log entry extra information related to the executed CI pipeline. The information to be added and the formatting must be configurable in the platform and without any change necessary to be applied to the source repositories where the pipeline definitions are stored.

The infrastructure information where the CI pipeline steps are executed can be automatically injected by the infrastructure platform (*e.g. for Kubernetes K8S based runners information like hostname, pod name, STDOUT/STDERR*), while the CI pipeline information must be added by the CI platform.

Answer (score 0):

From man [bash](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION):

> REDIRECTION
>
> ```
>   Before a command is executed, its input and output may be
>   redirected using a special notation interpreted by the shell.
>   ...
> ```

This means the redirection can be used to forward the output sent to *stdout* to a string processor that can manipulate the information and sending it back to *stdout* in a modified format.

The commands:

```sh
exec {STDOUT}>&1
exec {STDERR}>&2
```

will assign new file descriptors that are duplicates of the current descriptors `1` (*/dev/stdout*) and `2` (*/dev/stderr*) and store the values of those new descriptors in the shell variables `$STDOUT` and `$STDERR` respectively.

This will allow us to redirect to a different place the initial file descriptors `1` and `2` that are targeted by the commands that are executed in the shell environment. The new place where we redirect the log messages can be a new script where we can change the log message. Once the log message is processed to the new expected format, we can now redirect it to the initial *stdin* and *stdout* file descriptors that are targeted by the new shell variables `$STDOUT` and `$STDERR` respectively.

Now that we know what we have to do, we need to ensure that the redirection is applied to every command execution done in the shell environment.

The [exec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/exec.1p.html) command replaces the current process image with a new process image, while opening, closing, and/or copying file descriptors as specified by any redirections as part of the command.

The final command to would look like

```sh
exec {STDOUT}>&1 \
     {STDERR}>&2 \
     1> >(while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$(date +%H%M%S%N):${PROJECT_ID}:${PIPELINE_ID}:${PIPELINE_STEP}:$line" ; done >&${STDOUT}) \
     2> >(while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$(date +%H%M%S%N):${PROJECT_ID}:${PIPELINE_ID}:${PIPELINE_STEP}:$line" ; done >&${STDERR})
```

P.S. if you want to change all the log entries from the [Gitlab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/) pipeline job output, just configure the pre-build script for the [Gitlab CI runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section)

```sh
RUNNER_PRE_BUILD_SCRIPT='exec {STDIN}>&1 1> >(while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$(date +%H%M%S%N):${PROJECT_ID}:${PIPELINE_ID}:${PIPELINE_STEP}:$line" ; done >&${STDIN})'
```